# R: convert vectors of different lengths into a fixed time interval

Tags: r

I am working with 2 vectors with **different lengths** `105,102`. Call them `y1,y2`

Although they are different in length, each vector represents activity that happens in 30 seconds.

Assume the first element of all vectors start at time  = 0 seconds, I was able to plot them out with the following code:

```
y1 <- plot(seq(0,100,length = 105), rnorm(length(seq(0,100,length = 105))), type = "l")
y2 <- plot(seq(0,100,length = 102), rnorm(length(seq(0,100,length = 102))), type = "l")
l <- length(y1)
x <- seq(0,l,length= l)
y <- y1
plot(x, y, type = "l", xlab = "time", ylab = "bla")


l <- length(y2)
x <- seq(0,l,length= l)
y <- y2
lines(x,y, type = "l")
```

Now the above code will produce a graph with x-axes ranging from $(0,105)$. However, I want the x-axes to display $(0, 30)$ seconds.

I know the major problem is that the two vectors are in different lengths, but suppose I want to split the elements of each vector along the time interval $0 - 30$ seconds.

How should I approach this ?

Comment: Are you vectors generated by `rnorm()` your `y1, y2`? It is unclear to me what your x and y values for the line plot are. How do the elements of the vector relate to your (0,30) interval?

Comment: Yes. You can treat the vector as representing a time sequences of values generated by the `rnorm` function . I did generalise the problem a bit, but this should not affect the main idea of this problem .

Comment: The values of the vectors do not really matter .The main problem is that the vectors are in different lengths. But we can safely assume the first element of these 2 vectors always start at time = 0

Comment: You basically want to create a scatterplot, for which you need points in the (x,y) format. Your y values are the values from the vectors y1,y2. What are your x values and how do I calculate it for each point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP's just looking to equally distribute each y vector in time interval of 30 sec and plot the same. In that case, following should do the trick. Essentially, for `x` argument of `plot` and `lines` function, we need to provide vector which has number of elements equal to  number of elements in `y` corresponding argument, spread out from 0 to 30.

```
set.seed(1234)
y1 <- rnorm(length(seq(0,100,length = 105)))
y2 <- rnorm(length(seq(0,100,length = 102)))
plot((30/length(y1))*seq_along(y1), y1, type = 'l',col='red', xlab='time', ylab='y')
lines((30/length(y2))*seq_along(y2), y2, col='green')
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Well done, but yeah, the OP needs to understand what the actual sampling interval was for each of his vectors.  Without that, he is only fooling himself when plotting the vectors vs. a uniformly spaced x-axis vector.